# Strange multithreading behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am trying to execute three methods on a single instance in three different `Threads` in specific order. That is `methodA` should be called before `methodB` and `methodB` before `methodC`.

I have tried initially a not sophisticated approach with the code:

```
public void testFoo()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    service.submit(() -> foo.callMethodB());
    service.submit(() -> foo.callMethodC());
    service.submit(() -> foo.callMethodA());
    service.shutdown();
}

class Foo 
{

    boolean  methodAcompleted;
    boolean  methodBcompleted;

    void callMethodA() 
    {
        this.methodA();
        methodAcompleted = true;
    }

    void callMethodB() 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            if (methodAcompleted)
            {
                this.methodB();
                methodBcompleted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void callMethodC() 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            if (methodBcompleted) 
            {
                this.methodC();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void methodA()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Method A completed!");
    }

    void methodB()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Method B completed!");
    }

    void methodC()
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Method C completed!");
    }
}
```

I came into the following odd observations:

1) Executing the code as above only `"Method A completed!"` is printed out. Even if I change the boolean variables to `static` I get the same result.
2) If I change the boolean variables to `volatile` then all statements are printed in the right order:

```
"Method A completed!"
"Method B completed!"
"Method C completed!"
```

As far as I know this is expected, since it is not guaranteed (or impossible?) that a `Thread` is informed of change by another `Thread` action on the same instance. Is it true even if the changes are executed on `static` variables?

3) It becomes strange when I remove the delay `Thread.sleep()` from the methods having them run as:

```
void methodA()
{
        System.out.println("Method A completed!");
}

void methodB()
{
        System.out.println("Method B completed!");
}

void methodC()
{
        System.out.println("Method C completed!");
}
```

In this case the statements are printed always in the right order like in case 2:

```
"Method A completed!"
"Method B completed!"
"Method C completed!"
```

Can/should a `Thread` see the changes from another `Thread` acting on the same not `volatile` variables? What is the explanation on the different behavior/result  between `case 1` and `case 3`?

**Update:**

I think if the above approach were indispensable, the best solution is to use `AtomicBoolean` instead of primitives as:

```
class Foo {
    AtomicBoolean methodAcompleted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    AtomicBoolean methodBcompleted = new AtomicBoolean(false); 

    ...
}
```

I am persuaded that the purpose of `atomic types` is to guarantee consistent behavior in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need a memory barrier to prevent the JIT inlining the value of the `boolean` field.

The JIT can detect you don't change your flag in the current thread and can inline it, preventing you from ever seeing the change.

If you add `volatile` or a `synchronized` method (even an empty synchronised block) it prevents this optimisation.  Note: System.out.println is synchronized.

> Can/should a Thread see the changes from another Thread acting on the same not volatile variables?

It can and will see changes for other types as this optimisation may not apply to other type (Depending on your JVM implementation)

Also if you change the flag before the JIT has optimised the code, you will see the change.

I wrote an article on this a few years ago which has more details http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html